# Import dll file in Microsoft Visual C#

Tags: c#, dll, import

I am very new to programming in C#. I do have some experience in objective C.
I want to import an dll file that is in my references in Microsoft visual C#. 
is therea function like #import to import the dll file in my console application?

Comment: If it is "in your references" then you already imported it.  Don't skip reading a book about C# programming just because you have some objective C experience.  It is *not* the same kind of language.

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you **reference** assemblies (dlls) and **import** *namespaces*.

An assembly reference lives in the project/solution file for your program, and sometimes later on the in the .config file for the program. You won't see it anywhere in your source code.  If you already have a reference for the assembly, there is likely a namespace (or possibly multiple namespaces) in the assembly that you must then include in your source code with an `import` directive. You can see examples at the top of most any C# source file.

The distinction is that sometimes a namespace may be implemented across several different assemblies/dlls.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by import? linked at run time?

if not you can simply add a reference to your DLL in your C# project.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx